# Pasar una columna a string en python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo una columna y requiero pasarla a string ya tengo un código para llamarla desde csv pero necesito pasarla a string

```py
import pandas as pd 
def caso_Al(ruta_archivo_csv: str)-> dict:
   
    if ruta_archivo_csv.endswith('.csv'):
        try:
           
            df_Res = pd.read_csv(ruta_archivo_csv)
        except:
            return 'No es posible leer los Datos, verique la ruta.' 
       
        v=pd.Series(df_Res['Verduras'])
        c=pd.Series(df_Res['Cereales'])
        l=pd.Series(df_Res['Lacteos'])
        ct=pd.Series(df_Res['Cantidades Totales'])
        eli=df_Res.drop(columns=['Carnes Rojas','Carnes Blancas','Verduras','Frutas','Cereales','Hortalizas','Lacteos'])
        
        eli["Porcentaje Verduras"]=round((v*100)/ct)
        eli["Porcentaje Cereales"]=round((c*100)/ct)
        eli["Porcentaje Lacteos"]=round((l*100)/ct)
        nuevo=eli.describe()
        media=pd.Series( nuevo.loc["mean"])
        estandar=pd.Series(nuevo.loc["std"])
        porcentaje25=pd.Series(nuevo.loc["25%"])
        Xl=pd.concat([media,estandar,porcentaje25],axis=1,sort=True)
        union=pd.concat([Xl,eli])
        print(union)
    else:
        return 'Extensión Errónea'
```

Este es el resultado que espero

[image: el resultado que espero]

Y este el que obtengo

[image: y este es el que obtengo]

este es el [enlace](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ana0703/Reto5/main/Alimentos.csv) del csv

Comment: creo que solo deberias quedarte con la variable `Xl` y luego hacer `print(Xl.to_dict())` para convertirla a un diccionario

Answer (score 1):

Si pudieras mostrar todo el resultado correcto seria mejor, pero por ahora esta es mi solución pues se asemeja bastante al resultado.

Dado que ya estas concatenado todos los datos en la variable `Xl` ya no hace falta volverlo a hacer, de lo contrario tendrás datos repetidos y mal estructurados (muchos campos `NaN`), la solución simple es convertir los dados ya concatenados (`Xl`) en un diccionario, la variable `Xl` ya tiene todos los datos listos para ser devueltos.

```py
def caso_Al(ruta_archivo_csv: str)-> dict:

    if ruta_archivo_csv.endswith('.csv'):
        ...
    
        Xl=pd.concat([media,estandar,porcentaje25],axis=1,sort=True)
        data = Xl.iloc[:-1,:] #escogemos todos menos la ultima fila
        print(data.to_dict()) #mostramos los datos en forma de diccionario
```

**salida**

```
{'mean': {'Cantidades Totales': 3722.0, 'Porcentaje Cereales': 15.2,'Porcentaje Lacteos': 16.2, 'Porcentaje Verduras': 14.0}, 'std': {'Cantidades Totales': 336.06100636640366, 'Porcentaje Cereales': 6.610597552415364, 'Porcentaje Lacteos': 6.978538528947161, 'Porcentaje Verduras': 5.522680508593631}, '25%': {'Cantidades Totales': 3539.0, 'Porcentaje Cereales': 10.0, 'Porcentaje Lacteos': 14.0, 'Porcentaje Verduras': 12.0}}
```

Se escoge todo menos la ultima fila `Xl.iloc[:-1,:]` por que la ultima fila es `Unnamed: 0`, este es el resultado de tu concatenación, recomiendo que verifiques tus datos y que hagas correctamente las operaciones para evitar *fallos*